# Vagrant prompting for password without using key

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I am running vagarant using chef. When I am running vagrant up. Its creating an instance after that its prompting for password. Actually it should login with ssh key

I have granted

```
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh/.ssh
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/.ssh/authorized_keys
root@system-desktop:/home/system/Documents/dsrv169# vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.6.5
  config.vm.provider :digital_ocean do |provider, override|
    override.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
    override.vm.box = 'digital_ocean'
root@system-desktop:/home/system/Documents/dsrv168# vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 45.55.239.147
  User root
  Port 22
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

May I know what I required to do

Comment: Does is it still works if you don't override the default unsecured key?  Or save that id_rsa and overwrite it with the default unsercured key.  Just wondering

Answer (score 1):

it's just owner and group permission issue. After issuing chown it worked normally.